# SSAS Deployment Wizard - Issue with multiple connection strings

Tags: ssas, deployment

I've observed an issue with the SSAS Deployment Wizard.

I have two environments DEV and PROD.
A few weeks ago when I deployed anything on PROD I had one connection string only there to PROD (similar to this screen):

[image]

But today I've observed that the SSAS Deployment Wizard window looks like this:

[image]

Multiple connection strings to DEV and PROD.

Deployment went successfully but when I've tried to process the tables in the SSAS Management Studio I get an error like below:

[image]

Any ideas how to solve this issue ?
Is there any method to keep only one connection string to PROD in the DeploymentWizard instead of multiple to DEV and PROD ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened is that developers added new data sources instead of adding tables from an existing connection. In the future go to the Model menu... Existing Connections... Open. Then choose another table or query to import. This process is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh758440.aspx).

I don't believe there is a UI way of switching an existing table to use a different data source. The best approach is probably to just delete and recreate that table with the process above.

You should be able to delete the extra unused data sources from the Existing Connections dialog.